# How can we do genuine rails 3 polymorphic has_many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I want to have the following:

```
class Foo < AR
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Bar < AR
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tagging < AR
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user # etc
end

class Tag < AR
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :taggables, :through => :taggings
end

Tag.first.taggables # => [Bar:43, Foo:52, Foo:59, Bar:59, Foo:123, ...]
```

In particular, I *don't* want to have to specify `Tag.foo_taggables`, `Tag.bar_taggables`, etc. — that's the :source/:source_type method referred to in related questions, and it sucks.

I want it to just work properly with an array of disparate objects. Yes, I realize that they won't all have the same properties; that should be fine (I should be able to just rely on whatever interface all taggables *do* share, without caring about which kind I'm dealing with).

In particular e.g. tag.taggable_ids will probably have to be an array of id/type tuples, not just an array of int ids.

I'm using tags here just as an example — my actual problem has a different scenario but the same essential issue of polymorphic has_many :through.

In Rails 2, there was a plugin has_many_polymorphs that accomplished this, but it's defunct. [Kronn's fork](https://github.com/kronn/has_many_polymorphs/tree) doesn't seem to work. Is there a functioning method to get this in Rails 3?

Comment: Do you need it to be an association? Can't it be a simple method that delegates to `taggings`?

Comment: @RenatoZannon Doh, miswrote example. Edited to fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need `#build`, eager-loading it using `.include` or anything fancy like that, then you can use a simple method instead of an association:

```
class Tag < AR
  has_many :taggings

  def taggables
    taggings.includes(:taggables).flat_map(&:taggables).uniq
  end
end
```

Comment: That doesn't allow well for selection limits, etc etc things for which we have associations. :-/